# RAM Compatibility w/ Motherboard & CPU

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, hardware-rec

This is a followup to the previous question I asked which was closed for having asked stuff that would be irrelevant in the near future.

So. I'm a beginner to building my own computer, so sorry if this thread/post is completely redundant.

1st Question: Does compatibility matter at all with the CPU? Because after contacting support with a support team at computer builder originpc.com, they said that RAM compatibility is solely dependant on the motherboard itself..? If yes, then

2st Question: According to a post I found, the number 2933 represents the "clock speed" of the RAM, the higher the better. So, is the aforementioned CPU compatible any DDR4 RAM or just that specific clock speed? And if it were compatible with any clock speed of DDR4, would any speed above 2933 be just redundant or **what**?

Please explain some more about these related questions and help give some shopping tips for RAM, e.g. RAM Timing, latency and clock speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all three components must have compatibility with each other. Generally speaking, however, a stick of RAM compatible with a Motherboard is also compatible with a CPU that is compatible with that motherboard.

My best advice is to select RAM that has passed manufacturer compatibility testing. Most Motherboard manufacturers will provide an HCL (Hardware Compatibility List) indicating the makes and models of RAM they have tested and verified.

I also recommend that you purchase all your sticks of RAM in the same package (not strictly required, but it can give you a better likelihood of a good outcome).

As for your question on RAM speed, unless you are overclocking, DDR4-2933 is the highest speed the system can support, and you should buy for that speed. You may find that your motherboard supports faster speeds for use with XMP overclocking profiles, but you will need to make sure that if you buy ram faster than the CPU specifications advertise, the CPU can deal with it.